# Birt : specific Persian font is not applied to excel report output(problem with a specific Persian font for reports with excel output)

Tags: excel, fonts, report, birt, farsi

I have a Persian font and apply it to my Birt reports. the PDF outputs are perfect but in the excel outputs the font does not being applied to the content. In the Home-->Font part of excel, it is shown that the font is what I want but the content of the cell has the default (Times New Roman) font.
the minute I click on the cell and press enter or change the font size of the cell, the font style will be changed to correct Persian one.

[image: attached picture of my excel output]

Comment: This does not seem a programming problem, but more of a general software issue, better asked on https://superuser.com

Comment: it is definitely something related to the birt report engine settings so I assumed it as a programming problem. BTW thanks for your comment, I will follow that path too :)

Comment: Unless you program the behaviour of cells yourself using an actual programming language, it's not. It's simply a question about how to use specific software, and might even be a bug that you should ask the folks who make this application about. The basic guideline is "will the answer be a programming solution" (i.,e., code, an algorithm, an explanation thereof, etc). If not, it's not really a SO question (of course, [the on-topic policy article](/help/on-topic) goes into more detail). In this case the answer is almost certainly "go to the cell properties, and ...", i.e. app instructions.